# What is faster? "5 % 2 == 0" or "not 5 % 2"

Tags: python, python-2.7

I tried using timeit and time.clock() but my computer's speed is inconsistent and I couldn't find out which is faster, If this question already exists then I apologize but I couldn't find it.

Comment: This smells like micro-optimization. Don't worry about it, pick whichever is more readable.

Comment: Are you trying to find out if a number is even/odd for instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

easiest way is to actually time it, using python 2.7 `not 5 % 2` is consistently slightly faster:

```
In [1]: timeit 5 % 2== 0
10000000 loops, best of 3: 25.6 ns per loop

In [2]: timeit not 5 % 2
10000000 loops, best of 3: 24.5 ns per loop
```

using bitwise and:

```
In [7]: timeit not 5 & 1
100000000 loops, best of 3: 19 ns per loop

In [8]: timeit 5 & 1 == 0
10000000 loops, best of 3: 30.1 ns per loop
```

Comment: Try (5 & 1) & 1 - although, if I saw that in Python code - I wouldn't be happy

Comment: @JonClements,  added def faster but not something I would enjoy seeing either

Comment: @JonClements  (5 & 1) & 1 will evaluate to 1, while 5 % 2 == 0 will evaluate to False. Isn't the goal to compare forms that will produce equivalent output? What am I missing?

Comment: Stuff like (5 & 1) & 1 is *very* common in C and C++. Perhaps I'm out of touch.

Comment: @mathmandan depending if you want to check even/odd you apply the further `& 1`

Comment: Umm... or since it's been soooooo long since I've had to have the "luxury" of using such operators, I'm getting confused :(

Comment: @JonClements : & is associative (and idempotent), so no matter how many &1 's you put on the end: (5 & 1) & 1 & 1 & 1 ... &1 will be equal to 5 & (1 & 1 & 1 ... & 1) = 5 & 1 = 1.

Comment: As @rawing said above: you'd want to compare not(5 & 1) vs 5&1 == 0 .

Comment: Makes sense... my bad - Sorry Padraic!

Comment: @JonClements, no worries. I still think you are on the right track though, my brain is just too confused right now

Answer (score 1):

Testing `%2` (i.e. for oddness / evenness) can be performed quickly by examining the least significant bit of a number. (Do that with logical AND: `(n & 1)`). You'd be hard pressed to beat that.

But any potential performance gain might be probably attenuated in Python, so profile it and use if only, in your judgement, the performance gain outweighs the obfuscating effects of an expression which, although idiomatic in C and C++, may well be unfamiliar to folk with whom you are collaborating.

Comment: The question remains: `5&1 == 0 ` or `not 5&1`?

Comment: This might be the right answer for low-level code.  In Python, it simply doesn't make any difference.  Write the most readable code, and measure if you really need more speed.

Comment: That's good advice and indeed correct for python (although I'm no expert). But I couldn't resist putting out the bit twiddle answer. Added a little bit on the end so it has some sanity.

Comment: Heh, "Little bit on the end."  :)  Anyway, (n&1) & 1 = n & (1 & 1) = n & 1, so it seems to me that the second "&1" is superfluous. In particular (n&1) & 1 is not equivalent to the two forms in the OP's question, as pointed out in the comments to Padraic's answer. (See @Rawing's comment for two forms that are equivalent.)

Answer (score 0):

I belive second version (`not 5 % 2`) is faster since unary_not operation is faster than compare operation.